# repeating specific rows on every page printed

Tags: excel, vba

how is it possible to print the same set of rows on every page that is printed on excel?

1. how do i do this through vba?
2. how do i do this manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page Setup->Sheet->Rows to repeat at Top

Answer (score 0):

To add to the 'how do I do this through VBA' that you tag onto every question. Now that you have the manual way to do it, record yourself doing it manually with the macro recorder. It is a good way to learn the VBA syntax.